# RStudio Connect Server vs Power BI

Tags: r, shiny, powerbi

Has anyone done a comparison between R connect Server and Power BI. We are trying to work on the benefits of R Connect server over Power BI in order to convince our super strict IT management to go with R Connect Server.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should figure out what decision variables are important to you. [This RStudio thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/discussion-when-is-shiny-a-good-choice-vs-when-is-it-not-the-right-tool-for-the-job/707) goes into detail about the benefits, mostly if you are going lightweight it is better. Most likely your users are more technical and want more ability to build powerful tools themselves.

[Power BI](https://www.yurbi.com/blog/straight-talk-review-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-microsoft-power-bi/) seems to be better for the Excel "power" users. It does not handle large datasets well, and most likely this is for a non-technical crowd.

Consider the end users before all else, then work backward from there.